# Different behavior on click of two buttons on same page in Struts 2

Tags: struts2

I have `test.jsp` which has two buttons.on click of Display Chart button,it should open chart on new page which is happening using `target=_blank` in form tag. But problem is i don't want this behavior on click of Display Data button. On click of this button,I want to display data fetched on same page only,but currently for this button as well it is opening a new window .

**My code is:**

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Data</title>
<s:head theme="ajax" debug="true"/>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">

<s:form validate="true" target="_blank">
<table>

//Mapping of data from database

</table>

<s:submit id="submit" value="Display Chart" align="left" action="testAction"/>
<s:submit value="Display Data" align="left" action="displayDataAction"/>`
  </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

```java
public class TestAction  extends ActionSupport{

    public String execute() throws Exception {

        //code to populate DataSet

        chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
               "Bar Chart",     //Chart title
            "",     //Domain axis label
            "MARKETS",         //Range axis label
            dataSet,         //Chart Data 
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
            true,             // include legend?
            true,             // include tooltips?
            false             // include URLs?
        );
     chart.setBorderVisible(true);
     return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<action name="testAction" 
        class="testAction" 
        method="execute">
             <result name="success" type="chart">
                <param name="value">chart</param>
                <param name="type">jpeg</param>
                <param name="width">600</param>
                <param name="height">400</param>
            </result> 
</action>

<action name="displayDataAction" 
        class="testAction" 
        method="getData">
            <result name="success">test.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: I tried following ,but my action is not getting called .Can anybody suggest what I am doing wrong :<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $("#submit").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //prevents the default submit action
     $(this).closest('form').attr('target', '_blank').submit();
 });
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it done as follows :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openPopUp(){
    document.getElementById('testForm').setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    document.getElementById('testForm').setAttribute('action', 'testAction.action');
    document.getElementById('testForm').submit();

}
function noPopUp(){
    document.getElementById('testForm').setAttribute('target', '');
}
<title>Data</title>
<s:head theme="ajax" debug="true"/>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">

<s:form validate="true" target="_blank">
<table>

//Mapping of data from database

</table>

<s:submit id="submit" value="Display Chart" align="left" onclick="openPopUp();"/>
<s:submit value="Display Data" align="left" action="displayDataAction" onclick="noPopUp();"/>`
  </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```